# Id doesn't get passed on to controller's create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

My logic below where a variable's id gets passed on from the link, to `def new`, to a form, and then to `def create` breaks down in the last step.

In a view I have a link that passes on an organization's id:

```
createme_path(organization_id: @organization.id)
```

Def new (it actually has a different name but for the question I don't think this matters) in the controller uses this variable:

```
@organization = Organization.friendly.find(params[:organization_id])
```

The form that def new renders includes:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :organization_id, value: @organization.id %>
```

Def create uses this as follows:

```
me = Organization.friendly.find(params[:organization_id])
@user = org.users.build(new_params)
```

In `def create` something goed wrong. Upon creating a new user, I get the error message below referring to the `me =` line. What is wrong with the code and makes that `organization_id` is unavailable in `def create`?

> Couldn't find Organization without an ID

Comment: put your error log to http://pastebin.com/ and share the link.

Comment: I pasted what I think is the relevant part: http://pastebin.com/C2PZ4eMC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a mistake to get params value in `create` action. It must look like:

```
def create 
    me = Organization.friendly.find(params[:user][:organization_id])
    @user = org.users.build(new_params)  

    .....
    .....
end
```

Also please modify your `new_params` method, i think you need to modify there also. You should understand how rails pass params by using hash. Look carefully the bellow log:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ByeJN1oJ4CU2J1TgeXP***SJPpnOQINlMct8ZOskcxzVGGGFaM9B0g==", "user"=>{"organization_id"=>"2", "email"=>"test21@examepl.com", "username"=>"test21", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Register"}
```

Your params is wrap by user. Thus you must get it by using `params[:user][...]`

Please let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Yes, now it worked. But I don't fully understand it. Why should it be in `def new`: `find(params[:organization_id])` but in `def create`: `find(params[:user][:organization_id])`? P.S. params are I think set correctly using `params.require(:user).permit(:varname1, :varname2, :etc)`.

Comment: It's depend how you use form_tag or form_for in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You ***params hash*** is from ***user***, so it should be

```
Organization.friendly.find(params[:user][:organization_id])
```

Comment: Thanks Pavan. This worked. Since I had a little bit more back and forward with NaimRajib I hope you understand I'll accept his answer.